# Find the frequency distribution of the first character of the name in the table in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table like

```
key Name
 1   snake
 2   panda
 3   parrot
 4   catipie
 5   cattie
 6   pradip
```

Now I want to find the frequency distribution of first character of each row and sort in descending order and if there is a tie , it should sort in lexical order , so my output looks like :

```
p 3
c 2
s 1
```

Explanation : Since there are 3 words starting with p and 2 words starting with c and 1 word starting with s

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this.

```
import pandas as pd 

keys = [i for i in range(1, 7)]
names = ['snake', 'pandas', 'parrot', 'catipie', 'cattie', 'pradip']

df = pd.DataFrame({"key": keys, "name": names})
print(df)
#    key     name
# 0    1    snake
# 1    2   pandas
# 2    3   parrot
# 3    4  catipie
# 4    5   cattie
# 5    6   pradip

def get_frequency(s):
    d = {}
    for animal in s:
        ch = animal[0] 
        if ch in d:
            d[ch] += 1
        else:
            d[ch] = 1

    return d

data = get_frequency(df['name'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame([[v] for v in data.values()], index=data.keys(), columns=["frequency"]).sort_values(["frequency"], ascending=False)
print(new_df)
#    frequency
# p          3
# c          2
# s          1
```